# btrfs restore specific directory

Tags: linux, filesystem-corruption, btrfs

I have a damaged btrfs filesystem, and I am using `btrfs restore` to restore it. It seems to work.

The problem is that the damaged filesystem is quite huge, and I need only to restore just one directory. I see from the man page the option

```
-d directory
```

but the [wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Restore) I see `-d: ???`. Do you how to use this flag and if it can help me?

Comment: According to [btrfs-restore(8) Manual Page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-restore) it is `-d find dir`. Does that help?. You can also use `-D|--dry-run` (only list files that would be recovered) to verify what will happen.

Comment: not really. How to use it? How does it work? It restore only that dir? I get `check_mounted(): Could not open my_directory`. Do I have to mount it?

Comment: No idea .... :/

Comment: Use the `--path-regex <regex>` option? restore only filenames matching regex, you have to use following syntax (possibly quoted): `^/(|home(|/username(|/Desktop(|/.*))))$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How do I restore a specific directory using btrfs?

You can restore a directory using the `--path-regex <regex>` option with an appropriate regular expression.

You can also use `-D|--dry-run` to verify exactly what will be restored.

---

#### btrfs-restore - try to restore files from a damaged btrfs filesystem (unmounted)

> `-D|--dry-run`
>
> dry run (only list files that would be recovered).
>
> `--path-regex <regex>`
>
> restore only filenames matching `regex`, you have to use following
>   syntax (possibly quoted):
>
> `^/(|home(|/username(|/Desktop(|/.*))))$`

Source [btrfs-restore(8) Manual Page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-restore)